# Add admob view to the top or bottom of a UITableView programmatically?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

[image]

I hope to add a admob view at the top or bottom of an `UITableView`.
In Interface Builder it is easy -- just drag the view to the top or bottom of the `UITableView`.
But I would like to add view to the top or bottom of the table dynamically using code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add header or footer views to a `UITableView` by implementing the following `UITableViewDelegate` methods in your `UITableViewController`:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
           heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    CGFloat height = 100.0; // this should be the height of your admob view

    return height;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
            viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    UIView *headerView = myAdMobView; // init your view or reference your admob view

    return headerView;
}
```

For more informtation, see the [documentation on the UITableViewDelegate protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 0):

set the table's headerView & footerView